# How to implement third party GCM - CCS XMPP server using openfire?

Tags: android, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging, openfire

Currently I am working on instant messaging chat application in which I need to implement third party chat server.

I am following this [tutorial](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/antoine-campbell/google-cloud-messaging-cloud-connection-server-tutorial)

Complete project available on Github [here](https://github.com/antoinecampbell/GCMCCSDemo).

When I download this project it provides me with two project folders; the first is named **GCMDemo** and the second is **GCM_CCS_application**.

I import GCMDemo in eclipse; it provides me a GCM client for sending message and it's working fine.

But I don't know how to use **GCM_CCS_application**. This is a java application. **GSM_CCS_application** is not an android application; it is for server-side applications.

I have openfire server installed on my computer but don't know how to use openfire for this application. So please somebody tell me how to implement this server-side application.

Answer (score 3):

Hope you have figured this out by now, if not read on.. Basically you DO NOT need Openfire for this purpose. Google's server will do the job of Openfire. Your server application and your android application are both "users" or clients of the Google's xmpp server. The applications can connect to the Google server using your project ID and API key. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thnk u, can u pls tell how to run the BOTH android client app and GCM_CCS_application ? Do i need to run GCM_CCS_application first then run the android client (like GCM HTTP server) ? Do I need to package these two in one apk for release ?

Comment: @everydayapps I need a more detailed answer too, please..
I've been stuck with this things for days..

Comment: There's a full solution to this here ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056939/gcm-xmpp-server-using-smack-4-1-0

Comment: have a look at this tutorial: http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-ccs-with-xmpp/